# Grub rescue problem after installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot

I have dual boot with Window 7 And Ubuntu 11.10.

Yesterday I tired installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , by  Manually removing all Ubuntu 11.10 partitions, creating new partitions and installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, But then I got this error.

```
error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue >
```

The thing is when I let Ubuntu do partitioning for me it solves the problem, But I always do my own partitioning and it was working with me before, what had changed in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

I have both Windows 7 And Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on same Hard Drive, And the Partitions for Ubuntu that I have are :

1. `/`
2. `/boot`
3. `swap`
4. `/home`

I am not an experienced Ubuntu user And I hope I am not missing any necessary details, But please feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now its working, sorry for my newbie question but i figured out that boot loader wasn't installed on the same hard drive where my Ubuntu is installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before and I fixed thanks to a tutorial like
[this](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html).

I'm not gonna copy the whole tutorial because it's a large one, but I'll explain in short what to do.

1. Use the liveCD to check which partitions exists on your hd.
2. Mount your Linux partition
3. (Re)Install Grub.
4. Reboot your system.