# Error 15 after manually installing Ubuntu 12.04 dualboot windows 7

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot

(this post contains as the same as my preceding post on [Grub rescue problem after installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127662/grub-rescue-problem-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-lts) since I've post it on the wrong place)

Thanks God I found this page. I'm a newby from Indonesia, and I have a laptop with 2 OSes (7 and Precise) installed. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 manually by replacing Blankon 4.0's (an Ubuntu-based Indonesian distro) partition. I made `/boot` mountpoint and then chose it as the place for bootloading. As the result, I've been experiencing error 15 until now, and I have to boot my laptop from Paragon rescue kit every time I want to use it. Is there any way to solve the problem? Terima kasih (Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

"I made /boot mountpoint and then chose it as the place for bootloading."

That is the problem. The "error 15" is coming from an old grub legacy installation, Ubuntu has used grub2 for years now. What's happening is that you incorrectly installed grub's boot sector to a partition, while grub's boot sector should always go in the MBR. Boot Ubuntu then run `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where "X" is replaced with the letter of the *drive* you want grub installed to , like "sda" *not* a partition like "sda1". If you can only boot a LiveCD/USB system then you'll need to follow these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#ChRoot .